# Managing GKE and its deployments with Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I can use `terraform` to deploy a `Kubernetes` cluster in `GKE`.

Then I have set up the provider for `Kubernetes` as follows:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                    = "${data.google_container_cluster.primary.endpoint}"

  client_certificate      = "${base64decode(data.google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.client_certificate)}"
  client_key              = "${base64decode(data.google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate  = "${base64decode(data.google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}
```

By default, `terraform` interacts with `Kubernetes` with the user `client`, which has no power to create (for example) deployments. So I get this error when I try to apply my changes with `terraform`:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

 * kubernetes_deployment.foo: 1 error(s) occurred:

 * kubernetes_deployment.foo: Failed to create deployment: deployments.apps is forbidden: User "client" cannot create deployments.apps in the namespace "default"
```

I don't know how should I proceed now, how should I give this permissions to the `client` user?

If the following fields are added to the provider, I am able to perform deployments, although after reading the documentation it seems these credentials are used for `HTTP` communication with the cluster, which is insecure if it is done through the internet.

```
username              = "${data.google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.username}"
password              = "${data.google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.password}"
```

Is there any other better way of doing so?

Comment: If you find additional ressources on how to do this, feel free to edit your question. I'm currently stuck on the exact same problem, there does not seem to be a complete end-to-end exemple on how to deploy a GKE Cluster and a Kubernetes deployment inside it with the newer RBAC.

Answer (score 9):

- you can use the service account that are running the terraform

```
data "google_client_config" "default" {}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host     = "${google_container_cluster.default.endpoint}"

  token = "${data.google_client_config.default.access_token}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.default.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"

  load_config_file = false
}
```

OR

- give permissions to the default "client"
- But you need a valid authentication on GKE cluster provider to run this :/ *ups circular dependency here*

```
resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "default" {
  metadata {
    name = "client-certificate-cluster-admin"
  }
  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind = "ClusterRole"
    name = "cluster-admin"
  }
  subject {
    kind = "User"
    name = "client"
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
  subject {
    kind = "ServiceAccount"
    name = "default"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
  subject {
    kind = "Group"
    name = "system:masters"
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! My terraform was running with a GCP identity that had the necessary rights to the cluster, but I couldn't figure out how to configure the Kubernetes provider to use these credentials. Your first example, showing how to use "google_client_config" to get the OAuth token was what I needed. If anybody is in a similar situation, I'll add that you have to make sure you aren't specifying a "client_certificate" or "client_key" value when using this solution -- only "token" should be supplied.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user that you are using is missing the required RBAC role for creating deployments.  Make sure that user has the correct verbs for the deployments resource. You can take a look at this [Role examples](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-examples) to have an idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide both. Check [this example](https://medium.com/@Joachim8675309/deploy-kubernetes-apps-with-terraform-5b74e5891958) on how to integrate the Kubernetes provider with the Google Provider.

Example of how to configure the Kubernetes provider:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host     = "${var.host}"
  username = "${var.username}"
  password = "${var.password}"

  client_certificate     = "${base64decode(var.client_certificate)}"
  client_key             = "${base64decode(var.client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(var.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}
```

Comment: You should include key information from the link inside your answer.